# What can I use to make an ROC Curve in WPF?

Tags: wpf, graph, drawing

I want to make a graph of several [ROC curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roc_curve) in WPF.  I've found the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/), but I don't see an out-of-the box solution for what I want, just several basic graphing types.  Is it possible to build an ROC curve (preferably, an [ROC convex hull curve](http://home.comcast.net/~tom.fawcett/public_html/ROCCH/index.html)) in the WPF Toolkit?  Once it's built, is there an easy way to get the [AUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence-based_medicine#AUC-ROC)? Or is there an off-the-shelf solution I can just use?

Basically, I want a graph that looks like [these graphs](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume16/chawla02a-html/node10.html), but nicer and scaling with resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the visifire controls, and then added in a first series for the points and a second series for the convex hull.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you'll need to learn using [WPF PathGeometries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx). I haven't used them much, but from what I learned, I think it's possible to do the ROC curves.

If you want scaling, resolution, zooming. I think you'll be better of getting something that is already done like [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf.aspx), [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf.aspx), [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Charting/) or [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page). Otherwise you're likely to spend a lot of time implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I used ZedGraph to create nice ROC curves, even with the color scales at the side. 
It is not so hard to do, you just need to use ZedGraph's custom LineObj objects.
[Here](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Combo_Chart_Demo)'s example of using ...Obj objects in ZedGraph (you can add LineObj to the chart just as it is done with TextObj or ArrowObj there).